# Can we include UDT in include column list of nonclustered index in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

While working on index tunning observed that there is key lookup for UDT column in execution plan so wanted to know will it be fine if we include UDT column in include column of Nonclustered index to gain the query performance in SQL Server ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes that fixes keylookups - you should do a review of indexes and query stats to make sure you dont negatively  impact other queries by altering the includes (shouldn tbe a big deal if included at the end but its good practic to verify these things before going commando).